# php button value issue

Tags: php, html

I am brand new to PHP and have run into an issue with my buttons in a table.  When the button is clicked, it needs to get an ID number that is pulled from a database.  I have no trouble getting the data and passing it to the next page using...

```
<form action="ThisPage.php" method="post">
    <td><input name="Submit" type="submit" value=<?php echo $OrderNumber; ?> ></td>
</form>
```

Everything works perfectly, except that the $OrderNumber variable shows up on the button itself.  I would like the button to display as "Edit", not the $OrderNumber variable that is showing in the attached image.

[image: Buttons with $OrderNumber showing]

How could I make the button say "Edit", but apply a posted value of the $OrderNumber value?  I have been unable to find a way to accomplish the passing of correct and unique data while also displaying a button that does not confuse the end user.

To get to the next page, I am checking for a posted value at the beginning of the PHP script.  If there is a posted value, in this case, $OrderNumber, then the script carries the variables to the next page as shown...

```
<?php  
    if(!empty ($_POST['Submit']) )
       {
        $_SESSION['OrderID']=$_POST['Submit'];
        header("location:NextPage.php");
        exit;
       }    
?>
```

But if there is no posted data, the page runs and shows the rows representing the array of database entries.  All is well except for this button label.

Comment: you need to start  the session with `session_start()` before you are able to store/retrieve data in/from the `$_SESSION` superglobal

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't wrap `<td>` in a `<form>`.

Comment: Use a `button` instead of `input`.

Comment: value="<?php echo $OrderNumber; ?>"

Comment: @putvande why we cannot use <td> in <form>?

Comment: `<td>` needs to have a `<tr>` and a `<table>` as its parent. You can have the `form` inside the `<td>` or around the `<table>`, but not as a parent of `<td>`.

Comment: @putvande it is not effect on php code

Comment: No, it was just a side note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try This

```
<form action="ThisPage.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="<?php echo $OrderNumber; ?>" />
    <td><input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Edit" /> </td>
</form>

<?php  
    if(!empty ($_POST['Submit']) )
    {
        $_SESSION['OrderID']=$_POST['order_id'];
        header("location:NextPage.php");
        exit;
    }    
?>
```

add hidden field because we can pass any value in form without display we have to add this method.

Comment: Why should anyone "*try this*"? What did you change? Why was it changed? Why was that a necessary change?

Comment: i add hidden filed @Qirel and yes it is necessary change

Comment: My point is that you should always add an explanation in your answer what you changed and why. The answer by @LPChip has this, which makes it a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use a second element. Your code would look like this:

```
<form action="ThisPage.php" method="post">
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="ordernumber" value="<? =$OrderNumber; ?>" />
        <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Edit"/>
    </td>
</form>
```

On the next page, you can now use `$_POST['ordernumber']`. To use sessions, make sure session_start(); is placed before retreiving or storing and make sure nothing has been printed to the screen, nor any headers have been output before issuing a session_start();

Answer (score 0):

While it was short on explanation, the answer by Bhavin Sasapra worked perfectly.

The answer provided by LPChip was very close, but my script wouldn't run with;

```
<input type="hidden" name="ordernumber" value="<? =$OrderNumber; ?>" />
```

I had to use

```
value="<?php echo $OrderNumber; ?>" />
```

I am using PHP 5, so that may be the issue.  I will be sure to specify should I have another question.

And it turns out that you can open a form inside of a table.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!empty ($_POST['Submit']) )
{
    $_SESSION['OrderID'] = $_POST['Submit'];
    header("location:NextPage.php");
}    
?>
```